# What is the fastest way to extract the same key values from a list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

Provided a list of dictionary like:

```
[{'open': '38532.5', 'high': '38578', 'low': '38517', 'close': '38578'}, 
{'open': '38578', 'high': '38588.5', 'low': '38501', 'close': '38573.5'}, 
{'open': '38573.5', 'high': '38574', 'low': '38552.5', 'close': '38553'}]
```

What is the fastest way to extract a specific key and output the values as a list? If the key-value not exist in the dictionary, just ignore it. If I pick `open`, it will be, :

```
['38532.5', '38578', '38573.5']
```

Comment: `[d['open'] for d in my_data]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a list comprehension:

```
a = [{'open': '38532.5', 'high': '38578', 'low': '38517', 'close': '38578'}, 
{'open': '38578', 'high': '38588.5', 'low': '38501', 'close': '38573.5'}, 
{'open': '38573.5', 'high': '38574', 'low': '38552.5', 'close': '38553'}]


[i['open'] for i in a]
```

Output:

```
['38532.5', '38578', '38573.5']
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions will do this pretty quick.

```py
data = [{'open': '38532.5', 'high': '38578', 'low': '38517', 'close': '38578'}, 
{'open': '38578', 'high': '38588.5', 'low': '38501', 'close': '38573.5'}, 
{'open': '38573.5', 'high': '38574', 'low': '38552.5', 'close': '38553'}]

processed = [datum['open'] for datum in data]
```